# Maybe.map over a function that returns a pair

Tags: elm

I have a function with Type signature

```
a -> b -> (a, b)
```

And I have

```
Maybe a
```

How can I map such a function such that I can get

```
(a->b->(a,b)) -> Maybe a -> (Maybe a, b)
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the values you'd pass to this function and the output you want?

Comment: A function with signature `(a->b->(a,b)) -> Maybe a -> (Maybe a, b)` is impossible. What value would you return for `b` when you have no input of type `b` and no other information about it?

Comment: Also, a function with the type signature `a -> b -> (a, b)` can have only one implementation: `f a b = (a, b)`

Comment: @ChadGilbert There are infinitely many functions with signature a -> b -> (a, b)

Example: f a b = (a+1, b++"foo")

Comment: @duggi - Elm does not have typeclasses, so there is no way to bind any information about `a` or `b` unless you use concrete types (aside from using a few _magic_ typeclass-like things that Elm gets away with like `number` and `appendable`). [Your example does not compile](https://ellie-app.com/dLMH9L4zVa1/0). Your example at the least would need to specify `number -> String -> ( number, String )` or `Int -> String -> ( Int, String )`

Comment: @ChadGilbert What I meant to say is for any two types `a` and `b` there exist infinitely many functions whose output type is `(a,b)`.

What you claim is the only implementation `f a b = (a, b)` is the most trivial one where values a and b are not modified, just returned as a tuple. This is the cross product of two sets.

There could be other functions which can modify the values a and b before returning them as a tuple.

Comment: @duggi - We were specifically talking about the _type signature_ `a -> b -> (a, b)` which in Elm is a very specific thing. Sure, the general shape of the function signature `a -> b -> (a, b)`, substituting in concrete types, can have infinite variations, but the question and my comment were both specifically about the _type signature_ `a -> b -> (a, b)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to slightly change the function definition

```
g : (a -> b -> (a,b)) -> Maybe a -> b -> (Maybe a, b)
g f ma b =
  case ma of
    Nothing -> (Nothing, b)
    Just a -> 
      let
        r = f a b
      in
        (Just (first r), second r)
```